# How to display multiple images using swagger api (controller) in C# & .netcore 3.1 using SQL database server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger-ui

I have completed the code for logincontroller.cs and database file as well. But the last line in the usingdatabase.cs is showing error. Here are my code snippets:
Usingdatabase.cs
This function is used to get documents in the image format from the api.

```
public void GetUserDocuments ()
        {
            using (Con = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString.ConnectionString))
            {
                DataTable ds = new DataTable();
                var img="";
                try
                {
                    Con.Open();
                    string sqlquery = "Select * from Auth.UserDocuments where UserId = 2016";
                    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery, Con);

                    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Rows)
                    {

                        //Get the byte array from image file
                        byte[] imgBytes = (byte[])row["Image"];

                        //If you want convert to a bitmap file
                        TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
                        Bitmap MyBitmap = (Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(imgBytes);


                        string imgString = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes);
                        //Set the source with data:image/bmp
                         img = String.Format("data:image/jpge;base64,{0}\"", imgString);   //img is the Image control ID
                     
                    }
                    //LoginController imglogin = new LoginController();
                    **LoginController.ImageBase64(img);**//THIS LINE IS SHOWING ERROR.
                }
                finally
                {
                    Con.Close();
                    
                }
              
            }
```

Here is the logincontroller.cs

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetDocuments")]

        public  string ImageBase64(string ImagePath)
        {
            try
            {
                string filepath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\Images\\UserDocuments", ImagePath);
                byte[] imageArry = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath.Replace("//", "\\"));
                string base64ImageRepresantation = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArry);
                return "data:image/jpge;base64," + base64ImageRepresantation;
            }

            catch
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
```

**How to fetch images from the database and display in the swagger api?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### After test, we can't display multiple images in swaggerui.

You can use my sample code to show your image separately.

## Tips

*remove `data:image/png;base64,` prefix.*

## Code Sample

```
[HttpGet]
public FileContentResult show()
{
    // get strings from db
    string base64image = "/9j/2wCEAAkGBxITEhITEhISFRUVFRcVFRUVFRUVFRUVFRUWFxUVFRUYHSggGBolHRUVITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMtNygtLisBCgoKDg0OFRAQFSsZFR0tLS0tLSstLS0rLS0rLS0tLS0tKy0tLS0tNysrLTctNy0tKzc3LS0tLS0tNzc3NysrK//AABEIAOEA4QMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAABBQEBAA...WghBDURCECX/9k=";
    byte[] Picture = Convert.FromBase64String(base64image);
    return File(Picture, "image/png");
}
```

[image]